# suitable table for large text storing and counting in java

Tags: java, data-structures, string-comparison

I want to implement this.I will read a .txt file and then i  will convert it from Big letters  to small letters in an other  .txt file. Then i have to count them so that i find the most common letters  or words .My question is What kind of table should i use for that? Should i use a hash or a map  table ?The .txt files has about 5000000 letters words sentences.What is the table i have to use if i want to store compare and count and convert large files,so that i can retrieve it fast.
I have though a hash table

```
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

or should i do it with some other way?
Or should i use linked list ?
How can i implement it for Sentences or Words ?

Comment: Does Swing actually have anything to do with this, or are you just applying tags at random?

Comment: it will be implement it in swing.It's not random.But you can say also what you want as if it was random.It 's not a problem .

Comment: Your question states you have to find the most common letters _or_ words.  Which is it?

Comment: Yes but also to store the .I have a .txt and  i want  to search find the most common words count them so on....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here  http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J5c_Collection.html#zz-2.6
and here http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J5c_Collection.html#zz-4.
and here http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=65  and the bset in my opinion is here http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/how_to_choose.shtml.
Have fun

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count letter, a `Map<Character, Long>` or even `Map<Character, BigInteger>` seems more suitable. The concrete implementation is not that important. If your set of letters is defined and reduced (say the latin alphabet), you can even use an `BigInteger[]`, each letter can easily be replaced by its order in the array.

For sentences or words in these numbers, I would go for a database approach, with a row for each value you want to count.

UPDATE: An alternative approach for words and sentences with data structures could be with a tree. The rood node is the empty word, if you find "dad" from root you get the child "d", its grandchild "a" and its greatgrandchild "d", at this point you add 1 to the pointer of that last node (of course, if any of the nodes is missing you have to create them).

Comment: can you explain how would you do it for word and sentences.A row a word ?

Comment: can you explain it better?Do you have a sample ?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need a `Map` for each requirement.  For sentences:

```
Map<String, Integer> sentences = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

For words, the same:

```
Map<String, Integer> words = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Finally, for characters, use the following:

```
Map<Character, Integer> chars = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

`HashMap` should be the `Map` implementation you use, since you'll be doing a lot of searching within those maps.  The counting process does lend itself well to multiple threads, so you may need a thread-safe `Map` if you decide on that approach.

Comment: You think this would help me .I will implements a GUI with 2 text areas where the file will be added from the one side pure without any change and from the other side with the changes.I will use swing Map you think would be ok?

Comment: Swing map?  I'm not sure what you're asking for.

Comment: NO i will implement it on swing.YOU think that using a MAP would be a good choice.I want to convert from big to small letters then remove the punctuation and spaces and then count them .Do you believe that your approach is good for that?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you you can use the database approach and also you can use map to handle insert or update count method.

```
Map<String, boolean>
```

.

Also you can use batch processing to handle multiple queries at a time.

Comment: But how would you use the database approach?One  sentence in a row ? one  word in a row ? Can you explain it.If i have 50000000 words then how many space do i need ?The Free space becomes less and less

Comment: What is the relevance of that last link?